# Detect Tab Selection : Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ipad, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have five tabs in my tab Bar Application. I have give access to 3rd tab on if user enters correct password in popOverController. I wanted to present that pop Over Controller when user taps(selects) that 3rd tab. How should i do it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not do it through `viewWillAppear` and `tabBarController.selectedIndex` in `AppDelegate`? Or else use the `didSelectViewController` in `UITabbarControllerDelegate` via http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You can't use UIPopoverController on the iPhone.

Comment: Thansks for ur responce. I tried both methods tabBarController:didSelectViewController: and tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: but my popUpVC display after tab gets selected. I want, when user tap on 3rd tab, the current tab view controller should display popUpVC and if password correct then user see that 3rd tab or 3rd tab gets selected. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the U[ITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).
In particular consider implementig the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method of the beforementioned protocol, or even better the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIPopovercontroller to present the login form on ebtering into the tabbarcontrollerview which mean first action in viewdidload. Then verify credentials and remove the login popover. Thats it.